# How to get visual Swatch attribute image with image path of course

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I created a new phtml file and a custom Brands.php file located inside the Block folder. I also created a visual Swatch attribute and added some images. However, I am unsure how to display all the images. Currently, both the brands file and phtml file are empty. I previously attempted to retrieve the Label value and the option, but my issue lies in obtaining and displaying the image. How can I achieve this?